# Problem with the pronunciation of sequences of “in”, “a” and “un” vowel sounds

Tags: prononciation, nasalisation

I have come across the following sentence lately:

> **Je mets fin à un conflit.**

How am I supposed to pronounce **ɛ̃** (fin), **a** (à) and **œ̃** (un) after one another? Is there a way to go about it? Should I fuse the first one with the second or the second with the last one or all of the three? It's highly confusing for me as a beginner.

Comment: It's not been mentioned in the answers, but for most of France (and possibly other French speaking countries), we don't make a difference between "in" and "un". I personally would say "/ɛ̃aɛ̃/" here. If you're learning France French, you can skip all phonems from [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Close_vowels) with a (†) before them (I hope Belgian people won't kill me for saying that).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat A large part of France but not most of it. The difference is still made in the former Langue d'oc and Franco-Provençal area, which cover more than one third of France territory.

Comment: @jlliagre: Ça m'a plutot l'air d'être moitié-moitié https://francaisdenosregions.com/tag/brin/

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, un peu plus d'un tiers. Ce qui est notable, c'est que la plupart des gens de la zone qui ne fait pas de distinction est incapable de produire le son et même de percevoir la différence entre "in" et "on".

Comment: Tu peux t'entrainer avec « On en a un en haut » si t'as envie de te challenger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is usually a very slight pause between ***fin*** and ***à*** un conflit but all these vowels might be also pronounced in a row.

In poetry, hiatus tend to be avoided but in regular prose/speech, French has no problem with successive vowels, whether nasalized or not.

For example, the sentence:

> Tu as en haut un houx aérien.

has eight successive phonetic vowels */ty a ɑ̃ o œ̃ u aerjɛ̃/* but can be nevertheless easily pronounced by any native French person.

Here is another one that could technically be heard in a primary school:

> Haie a un *A*, un *I* et un *E* et eau a un *E* un *A* et un *U* qui se suivent.

/ɛ a œ̃ a œ̃ i e œ̃ ə e o a œ̃ ə œ̃ a œ̃ y kisəsɥiv/

Nineteen phonetic vowels...

Comment: I mean, that is absolutely horrifying! in Hungarian, we have words like "fiaiéié" (vowel-collision) or "megszentségteleníthetetlenségeskedéseitekért" (too long word) but these ones with their own special pronounciations are the worst!

Comment: actually, this is the best answer I have ever got on any SE site. it made me laugh so hard. thank you!

Comment: It seems Hungarian can even coin *fiaiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiéiért* ... ;-)

Comment: yes, but it is something that will never be said.

Answer (score 1):

If like many French speakers you merge /œ̃/ with /ɛ̃/ to produce [æ̃] with *æ̃* more open than *ɛ*, you'd have in theory the following sounds /ɛ̃aɛ̃/.  My guess is that this sequence would be nasalized throughout and be realized as [æ̃ãæ̃] with a glide from *æ̃* to *ã* and back to *æ̃*.

I think further that in an *allegro* style of speech, there would indeed be fusion between the sounds so that you'd end up with something close to [fæ̃:] as a way to pronounce *fin à un*.

Answer (score -1):

**Wow! Lotta great and good answers**

Parisian-areal native registers (mostly BCBGish)  that come to mind:

your answer is "the latter" (I can't say it fast enough to make it really sound as if the first was also involved in the phonation of the double-nazal final.

**One more almost-native vote for:** Monophthong + Diphthong.

So... which dialects are you most interested in after "bland/broadcaster-standard/relaxed-"textbook" ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On comprend rien au post, et en plus il semble induire en erreur avec le peu qu'il dit.

Answer (score -2):

While maintaining the nasal vowel, the *n* in **fin** can be liaised with **à**. As is normal when there is no consonant to provide a liaison and the second word does not start with an aspirated *h*, you can introduce a *glottal stop* between the words: **à'un**. (In English we tend to introduce a *y* sound. Do not do this in French!)

By the way, the English word is **pron*u*nciation**, not **pron*ou*nciation**.

Comment: You can't liaise here.

Comment: You can't liaise here because there's no liaison after singular nouns (except in a few fixed expressions like *fait accompli*, where I assume it's left over from days when there was liaison after nouns).

Comment: My apology; my mistake. I thought 'fin' was one of those exceptions.

Comment: Actually, looking on the web, there are some sites that list *fin* as an exception. But I don't believe it is in current-day French.

Answer (score -3):

You can't pronounce that too fast; use the indicated sounds, taking care to pronounce each nasal vowel fully so as to avoid  blurred sounds; it's difficult for natives too as the usual distribution of sounds in French is based on the principle of having a consonant sound between any two vowel sounds (principle that is, at times, transgressed).

There is no other way, no adition of phantom consonants, no fusion.

COMPLÉMENT 1

In order to pronounce « un » in a distinctive manner a slight glottal stop is used. Here is what the free encyclopedia says about the [French glottal stop](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_de_glotte#En_fran%C3%A7ais) (coup de glotte) ;

*Le français, en le nommant h « aspiré », possède aussi un coup de glotte linguistique, qui ne se trouve qu'à l'initiale vocalique de certains mots présentant à l'écrit un h- (mais pas exclusivement : certains mots qui débutent à l'écrit par une voyelle sont précédés d'un h « aspiré » non écrit, comme onze) ; ce h aspiré ne se manifeste normalement que par l'absence de liaison qu'il entraîne avec le mot précédent (on parle aussi de disjonction ; voir psilose), absence qui peut être accentuée par un coup de glotte devant voyelle mais se manifeste le plus souvent devant consonne (où il apparaît comme l'un des moyens de marquer la disjonction) : les enfants [lez‿ɑ̃fɑ̃] mais les hérissons (avec h aspiré) [le eʁisɔ̃] (voire [leːʁisɔ̃] dans une diction plus rapide), accentué en [le ʔeʁisɔ̃] quand on veut insister sur la disjonction et surtout petite hache, réalisé [pətit ʔaʃ] (ou [pətitəaʃ], avec un e caduc dans le Sud de la France) puisque [pətitaʃ] ne marquerait pas la coupure.*

COMPLÉMENT 2, suggéré par un [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36877/problem-with-the-pronunciation-of-sequences-of-in-a-and-un-vowel-sounds/36879#comment73617_36879), et finalement rendu possible grâce à cette [ref](https://www.academia.edu/9588576/Syllabification_en_fran%C3%A7ais_et_en_arabe_moderne_dans_le_cadre_de_la_th%C3%A9orie_de_loptimalit%C3%A9) :  *Syllabification en français et en arabe moderne dans le cadre de la théorie de l'optimalité*, DR. ABDELWAHAB ELSAADANI, Professeur adjoint en Linguistique française, Faculté de Pédagogie, Université de Mansourah

p. 6 de la référence

[image: ![enter image description here]

p. 10 de la référence

2.1 Syllabification et resyllabification en français

Dans toute langue, les segments s'organisent d'abord et avant tout en syllabes CV puis en syllabes plus complexes. C'est le cas du français:

- CV: cas
- CVC: car
- CVCC: carte
- CVCCV: carton
- CVCCVCV: cartonner
- CVCCVCVC: cartonnage
- VC: or, VCC: arme, VCCV: armer
- VCV: ami

p. 12 de la référence

[image]

Comment: That would be great to add some reference regarding the statement: *“French is based on the principle of having a consonant sound between any two vowel sounds.”* It is a first for me, and I could probably find hundreds of individual 
words that have two vowel sounds in a row.

Comment: @Montéedelait True, it would be better if this statement were supplemented with a reference; unfortunately, I can't get back at the source where I got that. Anyway, that's mostly true and the theory of liaisons is such that it tends to introduce these missing consonants between words (un navion, deux zétangs, …).

Comment: Pourquoi cette réponse se fait trasher et downvoter comme ça ? Elle est particulièrement riche et intéressante : Même un francophone natif comme trouve à y apprendre des trucs. Vous êtes raides, les gens...

Comment: 18th century French poetry had the rule that you should avoid hiatus; that is, you should not put a word ending with a vowel directly before a word beginning with a vowel. I don't believe this was ever the case with prose.