# Dit-on plutôt « à une autre occasion » ou « en une autre occasion »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation

Contexte.

À une autre occasion/En une autre occasion, j’ai posé une question similaire et je n’ai reçu aucune réponse.

Un ami de longue date m’a déconseillé d’employer la tournure « à une autre » en affirmant qu’elle génère un hiatus et que la langue française en a horreur...

Merci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il ne faut pas surestimer cette "horreur" des hiatus qui ne concerne surtout que la versification classique.

On peut très bien écrire:

> Il arriv**a à A**miens à 10 heures.

sans horrifier grand monde.

La forme ***à une** autre occasion* est plus courante qu'***en une** autre occasion*. On rencontre aussi ***pour une** autre occasion* et ***dans une** autre occasion*.

Les expressions ***à l'occasion*** et ***pour l'occasion*** sont d'ailleurs quasiment les seules à être utilisés face à ***en l'occasion*** ou ***dans l'occasion***.

Il existe une petite nuance : ***en une autre occasion*** ou ***en l'occasion*** est plus littéraire, plus emphatique que ***à une autre occasion*** ou ***à l'occasion***.

See also: [Problem with the pronunciation of sequences of “in”, “a” and “un” vowel sounds](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36877/problem-with-the-pronunciation-of-sequences-of-in-a-and-un-vowel-sounds/36881#36881)

Answer (score 0):

**I**

Il n'y a aucune contrindication dans l'usage de la  combinaison « à une autre » ou « à un autre » malgré le hiatus; on peut voir au moyen de cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&smoothing=3&corpus=19&year_end=2008&content=%C3%A0+une+autre&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20une%20autre%3B%2Cc0) qu'en elle-même cette forme est aussi valide qu'une autre puisqu'elle est énormément utilisée. Remarquer en passant que la prononciation de « en un autre » n'est pas non plus très facile (\ɑ̃ nœ̃ notʁ\) mais celle de « en une autre » semble sans problème (\ɑ̃ ny notʁ\).

L'article suivant est une discussion intéressante à propos du hiatus et de certaines conséquences mais ce ne sont pas des conséquences d'un effet généralisé : [Lexilogos, En Avignon](https://www.lexilogos.com/en_avignon.htm) ; cependant vous pouvez dire « à Avignon ».

Les deux forme sont utiles et utilisées mais elles correspondent à plusieurs contextes. Elles ne sont pas toujours interchangeables.

« **À** » correspond souvent à des notions qui se réduisent à celle de *direction*, soit littéralement soit figurativement. Pour « **en** » ce n'est plus la direction mais la *contenance*.

- À une autre personne il a dit quelque chose de tout à fait différent.
- Ce sera **à** un autre responsable qu'il faudra s'adresser.
- Il l'a donné **à** une autre organisation de charité.

--- --- --- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----

- La méthode a été avancée **en** une autre forme.
- **En** un tout autre temps il n'y aurait pas eu de difficulté.
- Elle serait avertie, mais **en** une autre circonstance.

**II**

Les deux locutions, « à une autre occasion » et « en une autre occasion », peuvent être utilisées de façon synonyme dans certains cas, mais seulement dans certains cas. Cela est valide pour toutes les locution prépositionnelles introduites par « *à* » et « *en* ».

SYNONYME     La synonymie est trouvée lorsque le sens de la relation est celle de contenance. Cependant, le contexte décide.

- Il a dit **à/en** une autre occasion que cela lui était égal.
- Le renard était **à/en** un autre endroit ce jour-là.

*exception*

- Il pensait qu'**en** un autre temps les choses se seraient améliorées. (*« En » ne convient pas dans ce cas-ci, mais il est difficile de savoir pourquoi.*)

NON SYNONYME     Il n'y a pas de synonymie lorsque la notion est celle de direction.

- Ils avaient remis la discussion **à** une autre occasion.
- C'est **à** une autre occasion qu'il faisait référence et vous ne l'avez pas compris.

*exceptions*

- Ils iraient en Italie s'ils avaient le temps.