# How at normal speed, is "on en a un en haut, hein?" pronounced by natives?

Tags: prononciation, nasalisation

I'd like to have this in narrow-detail IPA or by explanations of the sort "pronounce it as if it were spelled like ####" (made-up-frenchish-orthography string).

Also: is this a reasonable sentence, say, spoken\heard internally upon finding one needs a certain kind of screwdriver, and remembering that one has one?

Please state your dialect or register for any answer or answers. Thanks!!

(Originally came up in discussing good example utterances for demonstrating Academy French to American English users)

Comment: I'd say it's reasonable, though it might cause someone to crack a smile on realizing how it sounds. Personally I would do liaison only between the first three words.

Comment: I think it is a question of splitting it in rythmic groups. I'd say it as thee words:  "onena un enhaut"... but I am not a native, and I suspect that it might also depend on the exact context.

Comment: it is awfull for a native speaker to say that, at least to me. Dont bother the final `hein`, it will come after a rather long pause. There is only one liaison bwnt `on` and `en`, rougly speaking `onnen a un en haut`, just an extra n to apply.

Comment: @mh-cbon Your comment is surprising. The liaison between *en* and *a* is mandatory and always done and the sentence is considered unremarkable by everyone I ask, not at all awful.

Comment: These questions always surprise my wife and my cat when I start suddenly repeating them loud. I mostly agree with @mh-cbon, except that I would add the `a` in the first mashup: `onnena un en haut`. As from where: Versailles.

Comment: you are right. not sur why it slept out my mind. `onnena un en haut` sorry for that.

Comment: @WoJ Are both your wife and your cat native French? ;-)

Comment: Au Québec le _hein_ va se prononcer comme [_han_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/han?tableofcontents=0#Interjection), donc ɑ̃, un des sons qu'on retrouve en amont de la phrase... Ça reste que c'est de la p'tite bière prononcer ça à mon avis.

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa Une  ptite bière avec *a piece of cake* ;-)

Comment: Worth noting that en haut blocks liaison as a minimal pair to en eau.

Answer (score 23):

***On en a un en haut, hein ?*** is a reasonable and common French sentence. It doesn't surprise French ears at all. There are only mandatory (the first two) or forbidden liaisons here so no variants to expect on that side.

I pronounce it that way: /**ɔ̃.n‿ɑ̃.n‿a.œ̃.ɑ̃.o ‖ ɛ̃**/ which is close to Parisian French except *un* that I pronounce /œ̃/ instead of /ɛ̃/ there.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRUZMfw0Uoo&t=190s) where ***On en a un en haut ici*** is said around 3'13".

See also: [Problem with the pronunciation of sequences of “in”, “a” and “un” vowel sounds](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36877)

Comment: Do Parisians pronounce "un" as /ɛ̃/? If so, does that not make Parisian French non-standard?

Comment: @peanutjelly Sort of but not if we consider the de facto standard is how Parisian TV speaks.

Answer (score 0):

OnNONa UHnonHO (uh is nasal; ho rhymed with hoe)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, the pronunciation is wrong, you confuse "en" and "on" at the beginning.

Comment: I don't think it can be wrong, I mean, what dialect and what corresponding IPA are you imagining? Should I be speaking French, here? In certain/any contexts? Still need mentoring.

Comment: Actually, we French would slightly simplify the pronunciation of "OnNONa UHnonHO", effectively turning it into "Hon Hon Hon" when speaking at native speeds. We might consider adding some context to make the swap self-evident, usually adding "BAGUETTE" at the end, but it really depends if we're home talking to our family, or chatting with a stranger in a less casual French.

Anyway, something close to "Hon Hon Hon BAGUETTE" is how I would pronounce "On en a un en haut" by default.